# Is there way to get facebook insights data from URL and put it in php variables?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I have data like this, that's on remote URL:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "1234567890",
         "name": "data_name",
         "period": "data_period",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": 52,
               "end_time": "2013-01-21T08:00:00+0000"
            },
            {
               "value": 54,
               "end_time": "2013-01-22T08:00:00+0000"
            },
            {
               "value": 57,
               "end_time": "2013-01-23T08:00:00+0000"
            },
            {
               "value": 58,
               "end_time": "2013-01-24T08:00:00+0000"
            }
      ],
         "title": "Some title",
         "description": "Some description"
      }
   ]
}
```

Is there a way to get it from the link into php variables? I have good knowledge of php, but my javascript knowledge is very bad, so I have no idea how to accomplish that. From all this, I actually need only "value" and "end_time" variables.

Comment: What does your JS knowledge has to do with getting values into PHP variables? [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is your friend.

Comment: Do you need Javascript? This is JSON, so if you get this from a URL, can you use decodeJSON to turn this data into a PHP Object?

Comment: Get the content with file_get_contents and translate it to php variables with json_decode http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No JavaScript needed here. That's JSON notation, which can easily be parsed by PHP using standard functions.

Try this:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url); // You can also use cURL here if you like
$obj = json_decode($contents);
```

Then you can treat `$var` as an object. For example, `$obj->data[0]->values` will return you an array of objects containing your `value` and `end_time` fields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [value] => 52
            [end_time] => 2013-01-21T08:00:00+0000
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [value] => 54
            [end_time] => 2013-01-22T08:00:00+0000
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [value] => 57
            [end_time] => 2013-01-23T08:00:00+0000
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [value] => 58
            [end_time] => 2013-01-24T08:00:00+0000
        )

)
```

Comment: JavaScript Object Notation notation?

Comment: Whatever! :)
(and +1 to you)